# Google search is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google

I have a very peculiar problem. Sometimes Google search is not working. But if you type the website directly it works. Now to check whether it is a problem with my network, I connected the LAN to my laptop working on windows 10 and its working fine.

[image: google.com]

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you installed any browser addons?

Comment: And ... what error are you seeing?

Comment: Iam using google cgrome. The problem is there in mozilla and brave browsers.

Comment: when i type ping google.com in terminal the error message is:connect: Network is unreachable
In all the other browsers the problem is www.google.com’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: But if  I type directly facebook.com.. its loading

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the browser

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dig google.com` Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved it, but I will write it anyway:
Go to the IP network settings and check what is there in DNS settings.
Add to them the google DNS (8.8.4.4).
I had similar issues when I was only using 1.1.1.1 and 9.9.9.9

It seems that google doesn't want to leave you unattended...

Comment: Can you breafly explain the process